# Hide div when I click on a different image

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I developed an image gallery.
Each image has its name as its original state.
When I click on an image, the div with the name disappears and a new div with actions is displayed.

Is there a way to click on a different image, the previous image goes back to its original state? (presents the a div with the name again)

At this moment, when I click on the image I can hide the div with the name and present the action div, however when I click on another image, I cannot bring the previous one back to its original state :(

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgtubr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

**code**

```
<ul class="mdc-image-list my-image-list" style="padding-left: 10px;padding-right: 10px;">
    <li class="mdc-image-list__item" *ngFor="let product of Images; let  j = index;">
        <div class="mdc-image-list__image-aspect-container">
            <img [src]="product.image" class="mdc-image-list__image"
                (click)="eventB($event,j)">
          </div>
            <div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
                <div class="mdc-image-list__supporting mdc-image-list__supporting{{j}}">
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label divT{{j}}">{{product.Name}}</span>
                    <span class="mdc-image-list__label ImageButtonsG divB{{j}}">
                <a >ADD </a>
                <a>Save</a>
                <a>delete</a>
                <a>neu</a>
              </span>
                </div>
                <a class="EyeG eyeB{{j}}" (click)="Produto(product.id)"></a>
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>


      eventB(e, j) {
    $(".divT" + j).css({ "display": "none" });
    $(".mdc-image-list__supporting" + j).css({ "background": "none" });
    $(".divB" + j).css({ "display": "block" });
    $(".eyeB" + j).css({ "display": "block" });
  }
```

**Problem**

I clicked on two images, only the last image clicked should have the stock div and not both (the first clicked should be in the original state (div with the name))

[image]

Comment: It's bad practice to use `jQuery` along with `Angular`. Use `directives` to manipulate the DOM behaviors.

Comment: @SanthoshV I believe, but it was the only way to be able to develop this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to remove the styling you added when you invoke `eventB(e, j)`. Remove that style from all images and then add it to the image you clicked on.

In other words:

```
eventB(e, j) {
  this.Images.forEach((img, index) => {
    $(".divT" + index).css({ "display": "block" });
    $(".mdc-image-list__supporting" + index).css({ "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)" });
    $(".divB" + index).css({ "display": "none" });
    $(".eyeB" + index).css({ "display": "none" });
  });

  $(".divT" + j).css({ "display": "none" });
  $(".mdc-image-list__supporting" + j).css({ "background": "none" });
  $(".divB" + j).css({ "display": "block" });
  $(".eyeB" + j).css({ "display": "block" });
```

**A better way** would be to add a `selected` field to each image in the `Images` array:

```
{    
  ID:1,
  Name : "Name",
  Cat: "words",
  image: 'https://material-components-web.appspot.com/images/photos/3x2/16.jpg',
  selected: false,
}
```

and use that flag to toggle classes that control the display or hiding. then you will only set that flag to false in the loop I showed above and then set it to true for the clicked image, so your event handler function will become:

```
eventB(e, j) {
  this.Images.forEach((img, index) => {
    img.selected = index == j;
  });
}
```

In your html change this line:

```
<div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection">
```

To this:

```
<div class="mdc-image-list--with-text-protection" [ngClass]="{'selected': product.selected}">
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
.selected {
  .mdc-image-list__supporting{
    background: none;
  }

  .EyeG,
  .mdc-image-list__label,
  ImageButtonsG {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first one worked well, the second one (the recommended one) didn't work :( Thank you so much for trying to help me!

Comment: Glad it worked. To use the second one you will need to do some extra work - add a `class` that is only added when the `selected` flag is on, then add in your CSS file a selector of `.<the class of selected> .<the class to change> {<your css to apply for selected image>}`

Comment: I couldn't understand very well :(

Comment: Can you help me implement the second solution?

Comment: I edited the answer to address the second solution. Note that if you don't want to use class selctors such as `mdc-image-list__label`, you should add your own classes to these elements (like the way you added `divT` for example)

Comment: That being said, class names like `divT` or `EyeG` are not informative and also it is more common to use lower case and dashes to separate words, like so: `eye-g` or `div-t`